# Fix antarctica on a ggplot world map?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, geo

I want to plot a simple world map with gpplot, but when I do, antarctica gets cut off, because the coordinates don't wrap around, so the path goes back across the whole map, instead of going out the edges. For example:

```
world_data <- map_data("world")

ggplot() + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-90,90), expand=c(0,0)) +
scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
theme(axis.ticks=element_blank(), axis.title=element_blank(),
      axis.text=element_blank()) +
geom_polygon(data=world_data, mapping=aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), fill='grey')
```

Produces:

[image: Map without bottom part of antarctica]

But the sounthern most part of antarctica is missing - it should look like this:

[image]

Is there a simple way to fix this problem?

Comment: How do you think it should be plotted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `wrld_simpl` data file from the `maptools` package seems to have more reliable map data, including data for Antarctica that goes all the way to -90 degrees latitude. For example:

```
library(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)

ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data=wrld_simpl, 
             aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), fill='grey20') + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-180,180), ylim=c(-90,90)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(-180,180,20)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-90,90,10))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi @eipi10: your code does not work well when setting `coord_map()`. Antarctica looks weird.

```r
ggplot() + 
    geom_polygon(data=fortify(wrld_simpl), 
                 aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), fill='grey20') + 
    coord_map(xlim=c(-180, 180), ylim=c(-90, 90)) + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(-180, 180, 20)) + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-90, 90, 10))
```

[image]

Actually I found that most built-in world maps in R packages such as `mapdata`, `maptools` and `maps` don't work correctly with `coord_map()`. Highly appreciate it if someone can figure it out.